# Can I travel with my New Zealand visa on my old passport

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, new-zealand, passport-renewals

I am an Indian national and would like to ask a question about my travel to New Zealand. My old passport contains my New Zealand visitors visa which is still valid for 8 months. Recently my old passport has expired and I got it replaced with a new passport. I am planning to visit my friends there and just wondering can I just travel  New Zealand with visa in my old passport?

Answer (score 22):

You need to transfer your visa in your new passport. From the official [New Zealand Immigration](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/already-have-a-visa/transferring-my-visa-to-a-new-passport) :

> **Transferring my visa to a new passport**
>
> "If you have renewed your passport (because it has expired, was
>   lost/stolen or your name has changed), you need to transfer your valid
>   visa into your new passport before you use it to travel. This applies
>   regardless of whether you have a physical visa label or an e-visa or
>   other label-less visa."

Further from the same website [New Zealand Immigration](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/general-information/travelling-to-and-arriving-in-new-zealand):

> **Travelling to and arriving in New Zealand**
>
> Checking that you are OK to travel to New Zealand:
>
> - make sure your visa is in the passport you use to travel to New    Zealand – if you want to use a different passport, you’ll need to  make sure you apply to transfer your visa to the right passport before you travel
>
> **When you may be prevented from travelling to New Zealand**
>
> - Your visa isn’t in the passport you use to travel to New Zealand.

There fore you will need to transfer you visa into your new passport.

Most likely you will have to pay another fee to transfer New Zealand visa into new passport.

Source: [Immigration New Zealand](http://onlineservices.immigration.govt.nz/templates/Custom/OfficesAndFeesPopup.aspx?NRMODE=Published&NRNODEGUID=%7b8C2DAD76-7601-430F-92B7-2879007A6400%7d&NRORIGINALURL=%2fmigrant%2fgeneral%2fformsandfees%2fofficeandfeescalculator%2fLinkAdministration%2fToolboxLinks%2fofficeandfeescalculator%2ehtm%3flevel%3d1%26_ga%3d1%2e91089309%2e626609491%2e1484406486&NRCACHEHINT=Guest&_ga=1.91089309.626609491.1484406486&level=1)